# how to edit the hosts file to connect to a localhost port for a given ip?

Tags: linux, ports

I need to trick my computer to think that it is connecting to an external ip whilst connecting to a local port:

for example, 10.12.43.5:9000 goes to 127.0.0.1:9000
  but all other requests to 10.12.43.5 will go to 10.12.43.5.

How can this be done?

Comment: use a proxy. For example: a Webserver like nginx.

Comment: would you be able to provide an example? I had a look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html but I'm not sure what to do in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [netfilter](http://www.netfilter.org/) (also known as iptables).

To mangle packets destined to another host, use `nat` table of netfilter/iptables.

The following example will take any packet destined to TCP port 9001 on host 10.11.12.13 and turn them towards port 9002 in your local host. Note that this works only for redirecting packets back to your local host (due to nature of `OUTPUT` chain in the nat table).

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9001 -d 10.11.12.13 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:9002
```

You can test this with the following procedure.

1. Start [Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) in listen mode on port 9002 of your local host (`nc -v -l 127.0.0.1 9002`). The process will just stay and sit there, waiting for packets to arrive.
2. Apply the iptables rule above.
3. Execute another Netcat , this time towards the remote host (`nc -v 10.11.12.13 9001`). The process will just sit there, waiting for something to show up from the standard input.

Whatever you now type, should be seen on the listening Netcat.

This will most likely fail should you have existing netfilter/iptables filtering in place. The answer is simply an example how to do such a thing, integrating it into any firewalling rules you may already have in place is beyond the scope of an answer here.

Comment: very cool. That's exactly what I needed. Would I be able to do the same on a mac?

Comment: Anything is possible, with it takes more pain, I think. You'd probably have to disable Apple's own firewall (not recommended, seriously). As a nice bonus packet filter on Darwin does not support redirection on outgoing interfaces, so some `route-to` magic would have to accompany the `rdr` trickery.